# Choropleth maps by zip code

Tags: javascript, plotly, choropleth

Is it possible to build a plotly choropleth map that is divided by zip code? I can't find any answers on their website, etc, so I'm just wondering if anyone has done it, and if so, how would you set the "locationmode" and "location" features/how do you integrate data by zip code into the graph?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I don't think there is nor have I come across any.  Below is a link that was asked a month ago that was answered by plotly.

http://community.plot.ly/t/choropleth-maps-by-zip-code/1408

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - See below an implementation I did using a json file that is available on Github (https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON). The key line to fix is this one -> featureidkey="properties.ZCTA5CE10"
You need to specify the index that has the Zipcode in the json file.

```
# final_output
df = final_output[['ZipCode','City','Final_Labels']]

from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/master/ny_new_york_zip_codes_geo.min.json') as response:
    zipcodes = json.load(response)

fig = px.choropleth(df, 
                    geojson=zipcodes, 
                    locations='ZipCode', 
                    color='Final_Labels',
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                    range_color=(1,5),
                    featureidkey="properties.ZCTA5CE10",
                    scope="usa",
                    labels={'Final_Labels':'Cluster_Category'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.write_html("myplot.html")
```